# LINQ Query: Aggregate child sets from a set of objects

Tags: c#, linq

If I have an `ArtGallery` object that contains a set of `Exhibits`, which each contain a set of `Artworks`, how would I structure a LINQ query to return a set containing all `Artworks` in the `ArtGallery`.

I can do it without LINQ via something like:

```
Set<Artwork> artworkSet = null;
    foreach (var exhib in ArtGallery.Exhibits)
        foreach (var art in exhib.Artworks)
            artworkSet.Add(art);
```

Just wondering if there was something a bit more elegant

Comment: You should please write the ways you tried. We are here to help you find issues in the code, not to write code for you. It will be easier for you in that way. Please do not take me wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectMany will project each exhibit to a collection of art works and then will flatten all the collection into one:

```
var artworkSet = ArtGallery.Exhibits.SelectMany(x => x.Artworks);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to get it.

```
artworks.Exhibits.SelectMany(x => x.ArtWorks).ToList();
```